# How to find true cause of com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException?

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I'm trying to replace a field in an [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) document using the OpenOffice Java API. I'm using the `insertString` method:

```
  xText.insertString(((XTextField) fieldMaster).getAnchor(), value.toString(), false);
```

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
    [junit] com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException: 
    [junit]     at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.remoteUnoRequestRaisedException(Job.java:182)
    [junit]     at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.execute(Job.java:148)
    [junit]     at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:344)
    [junit]     at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:313)
    [junit]     at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JavaThreadPool.enter(JavaThreadPool.java:101)
    [junit]     at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.sendRequest(java_remote_bridge.java:652)
    [junit]     at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.request(ProxyFactory.java:154)
    [junit]     at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:136)
    [junit]     at $Proxy14.insertString(Unknown Source)
...
```

If I interpret this correctly, it's telling me that it connected to a different proces from Java, something in the other proces failed, but it's not telling me what the problem is.

I found that there are some environment variables (PROT_REMOTE...) that would let me log messages from these remote (different process, same computer, btw) processes, but only if I run an OpenOffice version with debugging enabled?

I'm using an OpenOffice version from an deb repository on Ubuntu, and have to interest in compiling my own OpenOffice version.

Is there any way I can get some useful error messages from the remote process to help me understand why my code is failing?

Comment: are there any other stack trace sections below that one?

Comment: no, that's the problem. I think the java app connects to the ooo executables (different process), using tcp or something similar. The other process has a problem, but this isn't communicated properly by the java side.

Comment: Anyway, i think the problem is caused by the fact that i'm trying to replace a textfield in a header using insertString. All the other insertString calls work as expected. Only the header fields throw exceptions. Don't know why, though.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a good way to determine what is causing RuntimeExceptions, but someone over on the OpenOffice.org forum solved my problem. I was using the API in a wrong way.

Instead of:

```
XTextDocument xTextDocument = (XTextDocument) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class,document);
XText xText = xTextDocument.getText();
xText.insertString(((XTextField) fieldMaster).getAnchor(), value.toString(), false);
```

I should have used the text from the anchor:

```
XTextRange anchor = ((XTextField) fieldMaster).getAnchor();
anchor.getText().insertString(anchor, value.toString(), true);
```

Apparently, text in the headers isn't part of the document. Which makes sense if you open an OpenOffice file. The headers are stored in a separate XML document in your [ODF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) file...